# Windows 10 Professional - Shortcut to both sign out all accounts and shutdown

Tags: shortcuts

How can I create a shortcut - that with ONE shortcut-button on the desktop:
1. sign out all users 
2. shut down the PC (in Windows 10 Pro)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single command, as shutting down the machine will sign out all user accounts.

Create a batch, or a shortcut, to the command

```
shutdown -s -f -t 0
```

`-s` specifies to shut down

`-f` specifies to force applications to quit

`-t 0` tells the command to shut down instantly (you can use and value in seconds to adjust this).

Comment: @Mole - No problem, please click the tick on the side to mark it as accepted if it has helped you :)

Comment: May I just ask you a complementary question regarding my Win-10 Pro?
I have four Windows User Accounts, all without start-up passwords. When I start up the computer, the last used account is automaticly signed in to Windows, instead of stopping at the Account list to let me select the account. The only way for me to stop startup at the account list in to give all accounts a startup password.
How can I make Windows stop at the Account list WITHOUT having any passwords?

Comment: @Mole Try typing `netplwiz` in the search bar, hit enter, and make sure the checkbox for `Users must enter a username and password to use this computer`. I don't think the password bit is essential, but if that's not checked it may automatically log in.

Comment: Sorry, this (netplwiz) only works if the user accounts have passwords.
I want the account list at startup with NO passwords assigned to the user accounts.

Comment: @Mole I suggest making a separate question for this :)